# SharedPreferences RecyclerView сохранение состояния выбранных Checkbox

Tags: android, recyclerview, checkbox, android-shared-preferences

Помогите плз! Никак не могу разобраться, как сохранять выбранные чебоксы , а потом при запуске приложения выгрузить сохраненные чебоксы. Проблема в том, что я не могу знать сколько Checkbox будут и знать ID каждого из них,  они создаются циклом .

```
public List<Melody> bindListMelody() {
        nameMelody = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nameAudio);
        pathMelody = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.pathAudio);
        mMelody = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < nameMelody.length; i++) {
            mMelody.add(new Melody(pathMelody[i], nameMelody[i]));
        }
        return mMelody;
    }
```

Мне как-то нужно получить позиции выбранных элементов , и потом сохранить состояние выбранного элемента.

```
//Adapter

@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final MelodyAdapter.MelodyHolder holder, final int position) {
        final Melody melody = mMelodies.get(position);
        holder.mCheckBox.setText(mMelodies.get(position).getName());
        holder.mCheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);
        holder.mCheckBox.setChecked(mMelodies.get(position).isSelect());
        holder.mCheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                melody.setSelect(isChecked);
            }
        });

        holder.btnPlay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                SoundUtils.playSound(position, mContext);

            }
        });
    }

//Class SharedpreFerences

public static void save(final boolean isChecked, String key) {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putBoolean(key, isChecked);
        editor.apply();
    }
    public static boolean load(String key) {
       if (settings == null){
           init();
       }
        return settings.getBoolean(key, false);
    }
```

Comment: А в чём конкретно у вас проблема? Кажется весь код у вас есть и вам нужно просто вызвать методы save и load

Comment: Вот допустим для каждого элемента создаю key .save(mMelodies.get(position).isSelect(),CHECKED_PREF+position); (Не уверен правильно ли)Потом при выгрузке, как мне присвоить каждому checkbox свое состояние из SP?

Comment: Например, вы можете сохранять с ключом `mMelodies.get(position).getName()` и значением `mMelodies.get(position).isChecked()` при смене выбранности (в `onCheckedChanged`). А при формировании массива соответственно из префов по этому ключу вытаскивать значение и в `Melody` его сохранять. И в `onBindViewHolder` это значение использовать для проставления изначального значения.

Comment: Спасибо! Помогло.